# Form Submit calling adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a form that call a procedure onsubmit, this procedure parse the document and create a json object which is passed to an adapter. It seems when the onSubmit procedure end, the call to the adapter is killed and then the onFailure method of the adapter is called.

My question is how I can wait in my onSubmit procedure that the adapter is finished.

If I add a flag in the onSuccess and wait until the flag is set, I will not capture real failure. If I add a flag in the onFailure, as the onFailure is called because the process is killed, I will not be able to wait the end of the process.

It works if I add an alert after the call to the adapter in the onSubmit procedure and wait that the onSuccess is triggered...

Here some code:

```
function postCustomer(content) {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'myAdapter',
        procedure : 'postCustomerByContent',
        parameters : [ content ]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : postCustomerSuccess,
        onFailure : postCustomerFailure,
        timeout: 30000
    });
}

function postCustomerSuccess(result) {
    var httpStatusCode = result.status;
    if (200 == httpStatusCode) {
        var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
        var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
        if (true == isSuccessful) {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show('Title', "Success", [{text : 'OK'}]);
        } else {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show('Title', "Error. isSuccessful=" + isSuccessful, [{text : 'OK'}]);
        }
    } else {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show('title', "Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode, [{text : 'OK'}]);
    }
}

function postCustomerFailure(result) {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show('Title', "Failed:"+result, [{text : 'OK'}]);
}

function formSubmit() {
    var application = document.forms["application"], initial = application["ibmerName"].value, email, name, organizationName = application['organizationName'].value, primaryContactName = application['primaryContactName'].value, primaryContactEmail = application['primaryContactEmail'].value, organizationAddress = application['organizationAddress'].value, primaryContactPhoneNumber = application['primaryContactPhoneNumber'].value, country = application['country'].value, organizationType = application['organizationType'].value;
    if (initial == "xxx") {
        email = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        name = "xxx";
    } else if (initial == "yyy") {
        email = "yyyyyyyy";
        name = "yyyyyyyyyy";
    } else {
        email = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    }
    var content = '{"email":"' + email + '","name":"' + name
            + '","organizationName":"' + organizationName
            + '","primaryContactName":"' + primaryContactName
            + '","primaryContactEmail":"' + primaryContactEmail
            + '","organizationAddress":"' + organizationAddress
            + '","primaryContactPhoneNumber":"' + primaryContactPhoneNumber
            + '","country":"' + country + '","organizationType":"'
            + organizationType + '"}';
    postCustomer(content);

    alert(content);

}
```

Any idea?
Thx

Comment: Found the solution: in the form I was using onSubmit with a button type 'submit'. I removed the onSubmit from the format and changed the button type as 'button' and add 'onclick' with the call to formSubmit().

Answer (score 0):

is the page refreshing, if so, you have to do a return false at the end of your formSubmit function.